# How to create Multilevel Colored Boxes using tcolorbox/any other package?

Tags: formatting, color, tcolorbox, boxes, framed

`tcolorbox` Manual provides the following example:

[image]

Can anybody please suggest me how to create exactly this type of box - The no. of rows to add must be flexible(It seems that tcolorbox has no option other than top & bottom):

[image]

Comment: `mdframed` would be my first choice

Comment: I haven't used <mdframed> package much, but I feel that boxes drawn using <tcolorbox> are more beautiful.

Comment: @SandeepSingh: Both packages can draw frames. how it looks that is your turn.

Comment: @Marco: Can you please post some example code which shows how to achieve this using tcolorbox? Thanks.

Comment: Later I can. At the momemnt I have no LaTeX.

Comment: Thanks. I am waiting for some descriptive response to this question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

And here's one possibility using `mdframed`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\definecolor{mybrown}{RGB}{128,64,0}

\mdfdefinestyle{mystyle}{%
linecolor=mybrown,outerlinewidth=1pt,%
frametitlerule=true,frametitlefont=\sffamily\bfseries\color{white},%
frametitlerulewidth=1pt,frametitlerulecolor=mybrown,%
frametitlebackgroundcolor=mybrown,
backgroundcolor=mybrown!05,
innertopmargin=\topskip,
roundcorner=5pt
}
\mdtheorem[style=mystyle]{example}{Example}

\gdef\Sepline{%
  \par\noindent\makebox[\linewidth][l]{%
  \hspace*{-\mdflength{innerleftmargin}}%
   \tikz\draw[thick,dashed,gray!60] (0,0) --%
        (\textwidth+\the\mdflength{innerleftmargin}+\the\mdflength{innerrightmargin},0);
  }\par\nobreak}


\begin{document}

\begin{example}[The Title]
The contents of the first part.
\Sepline
\noindent The contents of the second part.
\Sepline
\noindent The contents of the third part.
\Sepline
\noindent The contents of the fourth part.
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's now a modification not using a theorem-like structure, but a simple environment with a mandatory argument to provide a title:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\definecolor{mybrown}{RGB}{128,64,0}

\mdfdefinestyle{mystyle}{%
linecolor=mybrown,outerlinewidth=1pt,%
frametitlerule=true,frametitlefont=\sffamily\bfseries\color{white},%
frametitlerulewidth=1pt,frametitlerulecolor=mybrown,%
frametitlebackgroundcolor=mybrown,
backgroundcolor=mybrown!05,
innertopmargin=\topskip,
roundcorner=5pt
}
\newmdenv[style=mystyle]{exa}
\newenvironment{example}[1]
  {\begin{exa}[frametitle=#1]}
  {\end{exa}}

\gdef\Sepline{%
  \par\noindent\makebox[\linewidth][l]{%
  \hspace*{-\mdflength{innerleftmargin}}%
   \tikz\draw[thick,dashed,gray!60] (0,0) --%
        (\textwidth+\the\mdflength{innerleftmargin}+\the\mdflength{innerrightmargin},0);
  }\par\nobreak}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}{The Title}
The contents of the first part.
\Sepline
\noindent The contents of the second part.
\Sepline
\noindent The contents of the third part.
\Sepline
\noindent The contents of the fourth part.
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't want "Example 1:" To be displayed as the title. I just want my own title here. Can you please suggest the necessary change in the above code to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: @billjoy please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 24):

[`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) doesn't provide code to add more than one lower part. But you could add additional lines:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tikz,tcolorbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\DrawLine}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[use as bounding box] (0,0) -- (\linewidth,0);
  \draw[color=red!75!black,dashed,dash phase=2pt]
        (0-\kvtcb@leftlower-\kvtcb@boxsep,0)--
        (\linewidth+\kvtcb@rightlower+\kvtcb@boxsep,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5,colframe=red!75!black,title=My nice heading]

This is another \textbf{tcolorbox}.

\tcblower

Here, you see the lower part of the box.

\DrawLine

and some more

\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

This yields:

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to put the following code: "\makeatletter
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[use as bounding box] (0,0) -- (\linewidth,0);
\draw[color=red!75!black,dashed,dash phase=2pt]
      (0-\kvtcb@leftlower-\kvtcb@boxsep,0)--
      (\linewidth+\kvtcb@rightlower+\kvtcb@boxsep,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\makeatother" into a single command so that multiple rows can be added just by adding a single line, like: /newcommand ? I tried putting them into a single block using "\newcommand" but getting errors.

Comment: You must put the `\makeatletter` *before* the `\newcommand`, (and the `\makeatother` after the closing brace).

Comment: I am facing problem. My code:
\makeatother
\newcommand {\mybox}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\path[use as bounding box] (0,0) -- (\linewidth,0);%
\draw[color=red!75!black,dashed,dash phase=2pt]%
      (0-\kvtcb@leftlower-\kvtcb@boxsep,0)--%
      (\linewidth+\kvtcb@rightlower+\kvtcb@boxsep,0);%
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\makeatletter
\begin{document}
\makeatletter

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5,colframe=red!75!black,title=My nice heading]
This is another \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\tcblower
Here, you see the lower part of the box.
\mybox
and some more
\mybox
and even more
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}

Comment: :@Ulrike:My box display is not proper. Can you please help me correct the above code.

Comment: I don't have the time currently to make tests, but one error is obvious: use `\makeatletter` (= "make @ to a letter so that is can be used in command names") before the `\newcommand` not `\makeatother`.

Comment: Nice idea! I updated the answer accordingly. Afaik there is still no other way (maybe intensely abusing subtitles ...).