# Is it possible to use \tcblower many times in tcolorbox?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox

I know that in tcolorbox one can use `\tcblower` command to change the current background style. My question is whether it is possible to switch the upper and lower background style in a tcolorbox for more than once?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{most}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
    enhanced,
    beamer,
    breakable,]
   I want to here show the upper style
   \tcblower
   I want to here show the lower style
   % \tcbupper
   This is the third paragraph, I want to here repeat the upper style
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68010/how-to-create-multilevel-colored-boxes-using-tcolorbox-any-other-package  --does this answer

Comment: @js bibra Thanks for your comment. The linked post draw the line to split the different parts. I wonder whether it is possible to use background color to split them as does in beam style.